# Given the equations of two spheres, how do you find the plane of their ntersection?

Tags: geometry, 3d, spheres

For example, given the two intersecting spheres
$$S_0: (x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 + (z-z_0)^2 = r_0^2$$
$$S_1: (x-x_1)^2 + (y-y_1)^2 + (z-z_1)^2 = r_1^2$$

How would you find the equation of the plane that contains the points in the intersection of spheres $S_0$ and $S_1$?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: 1) Find the normal vector of the plane from the two centers. 2) Find the point lying on the line that connects the two centers using the radii. 3) Form the equation of the plane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite your equations like this for $i\in\{0,1\}$:

$$(x^2+y^2+z^2)+(-2x_i)x+(-2y_i)y+(-2z_i)z
=r_i^2-x_i^2-y_i^2-z_i^2$$

Now subtract the two equations from one another, i.e. subtract left side from left side and right side from right side. The $(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ terms will cancel one another and disappear, so you will end up with a linear equation in your coordinates, which is the equation of a plane.

Why does that work? Points which satisfy both the equations must necessarily also satisfy their difference. That's because if the equation is satisfied, both left and right hand side are equal so you are subtracting equal values from equal values. Which means that the points on the circle of intersection will satisfy the difference as well. On the other hand, the difference has the form of a plane, so it must be the plane containing that circle of intersection.

Note that you might have situations where the spheres don't really intersect because they are too far apart. The difference equation would still find a plane between them. The plane that you get from this is called the radical plane of the two spheres. You might also have two concentric spheres, in which case the linear terms would cancel as well, and you'd no longer get the equation of a plane. The radical plane is not defined for concentric spheres.

Comment: "Note that you might have situations where the spheres don't really intersect because they are too far apart."  Or concentric. Or they are the same sphere. By symmetry, no plane could be distinguished as the radical plane in such cases (although perhaps in projective geometry, the plane at infinity wouldn't be barred by symmetry).

Comment: I've included some of your comment in by answer, @Acccumulation. I doubt the situation would be any different in projective geometry. I don't see a limit process where a finite radical plane would converge to the plane at infinity as the spheres approach concentricity. Also the equation of the plane would end up as homogeneous null vector there. The only difference I see is that the difference of conics would again be a conic, namely the degenerate conic which is the product of the radical plane and the plane at infinity. You'd factor out the latter to obtain the former.